# Does it make sense to clean pressure solenoid when changing transmission fluid?

Tags: transmission, cleaning

I was just watching "Ratches And Wrenches" where he had a truck which would not shift. He did a transmission fluid and filter change and then removed the solenoid and replaced with a new one. But at one point showed how the solenoid had its own little grills, like a filter, and how they were blocked up with metal bits. He said he could probably clean it but would not risk it as he had the new part.

This got me thinking why in general do we not include this solenoid cleaning when we have the pan dropped and fluid changed?

It appears it would only take a minute or two, and worse case, just require a couple of new o-rings.

Is there some type of inherit risk of future failure if you remove and clean the solenoid?

Any other reason why this would not be recommended?

Seems silly to clean the fluid, change the filter but leave the solenoid clogged a bit so the pressure sensor cannot get correct data.

Answer (score 0):

As he was, apparently solving a specific issue "not shifting" then changing the solenoid could have been part of the solution or most of it and the fluid change only incidental.

For a simple fluid change without shifting issue why replace something without reason?
"If it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Comment: I do hear if its not broke don't fix it a lot. I'm completely new to car maintenance so noob's ask such questions. It seems to me in this case if the solenoid is a little clogged, then pressure sensor will get low readings which will have a measurable effect like delayed cooling fan activation and more heat in the transmission. Normally I agree, but I would argue that anything that could increase the heat of a component, would qualify as 'partially broken' and not 'ain't broke' ?

Comment: Note also I read your response carefully. I was not suggesting replacing the solenoid. Merely to remove it, clean it and replace it, with perhaps a few cents for o-rings. cheers.

Comment: Although it's a nice sound bite, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" is not always good advice. If disassembly of something takes 3 or 4 hours, I'm gonna go ahead and replace any wear items in there even if everything's fine, just to delay the next disassembly.

Answer (score -1):

I think the prevalent assumption is that there would probably be rare occasions where the mesh is clogged, but all solenoids are still in original working condition.

So cleaning them would then be considered a budget/partial fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).